# How to get AWS ECS Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have my microservice running in AWS ECS, and I want to tell which region this service is running in.  Do they have a meta data service for me get my microservice region?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first is to use the [Metadata file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html). This feature is disabled by default so you'll need to turn it on.
Run `cat $ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE` on linux after enabling it to see the metadata. The ENV var stores the file location.

The second is to use the [HTTP metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html). There are two potential endpoints here (version 2 and 3) depending on how the instance is launched, so check the docs.

In either case the region is not a specific property of the metadata, but it can be inferred from the ARN.